# Trouble adding data to options table

Tags: hooks, options

I am trying to create a function that adds an option containing a subscription list to the options table. (This list is eventually referenced by a plug-in.) I am having some problems as there are two functions (one that calls the other if needed) and I'm not whether to reference the global `user_ID` or the `$player->ID` from `get_users()`. I'm also not sure I'm using the right hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', "forum_subscribe_member_player" );

function forum_subscribe_member_player()
{
    global $user_ID;
    $players= get_users();

    foreach($players as $player)
    {
        $playeremail = get_userdata($player->ID, 'user_email');
        if(!empty($playeremail) && $player->user_level >= 1)
        {                   
            $list = get_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", array());


            if( is_player_subscribed($player->ID)) //remove user if already exists (user clicked unsubscribe)
            {
                $key = array_search($playeremail, $list);
                unset($list[$key]);
            }
            else
                $list[] = $playeremail;
            update_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", $list);
        }
    }       
}

function is_player_subscribed($user_ID)
{
    $players= get_users();

    foreach($players as $player)
    {       
      if($player->ID)
      {
        $playeremail = get_userdata($user_ID, 'user_email');
        $list = get_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", array());
        if(in_array($playeremail, $list))
        {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: When is this supposed to run? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: It suppposed to loop through all the usersis to add It is supposed to run

Comment: You are running this on every page load then. That is very bad. Where does it need to run? Possibly once to initialize the existing users and then only when a new user registers, right?

Comment: Exactly! It supposed to loop through all the users (contributors or user_level >=1) and add their email addresses as an array in an option called `mf_forum_subscribers_1` but not if they are already subscribed (i.e. already in the  array) so yes when a user registers would be good then.